# AngularJS - passing this.value into a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, function, angularjs-scope

I have this code in native javascript and it works all right. it logs the textbox's current value

```
<script>
    var boom = function(val) {
        console.log(val);
    };
</script>

<input type="text" onclick="boom(this.value)"/>
```

Then I want to do the same on AngularJS without using model. Here is the code:

```
$scope.boom = function(val) {
    console.log(val);
};

<input type="text" ng-click="boom(this.value)"/>
```

But it always logs **undefined**!
*Why*?

Comment: You should read some documentation about angularJS's controllers, scope, and directives. Follow some tutorials before start typing code.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As I know, `this` in context of `ng-*` is a `scope`.
You may access via `boom($event.target.value)`.

Comment: Perfect! Nice one buddy!

Answer (score 10):

The Angular way is to use `ngModel`:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="input" ng-click="boom()"/>
```

and in controller:

```
var boom = function() {
    console.log($scope.input);
};
```

`this.input` will also work since `this` points to current scope object.

If you still want to avoid model then you can use event object:

```
<input type="text" ng-click="boom($event)"/>
```

and

```
var boom = function($event) {
    console.log($event.target.value);
};
```

Comment: Why not `ng-click="boom(input)"`? No need to pass in the event.

Comment: yeah, you can just use ng-click="boom(input)" just @yoshi said. And also I need not to use model for some reason

Answer (score 1):

'value' is not defined in scope.

I'll expand a little Miraage answer..

`this` will refer to the scope. If you want to access the DOM element use $event. In the callback function you can get the DOM element value using `boom($event.target.value)`