# $event.target.value not returning as expected

Tags: angularjs

Referencing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26463491/angularjs-passing-this-value-into-a-function), what I have should have worked:

```
<div ng-show="openGroup == group.id" ng-repeat="member in group.members">
    <ion-item class="item item-accordion item-toggle">
        <h3>{{ member.firstName }} {{ member.lastName }}</h3>
        <label ng-show="member.lead">Lead</label>
        <label class="toggle toggle-positive">
            <input ng-click="toggleClicked(member.id, $event.target.value)" type="checkbox">
            <div class="track">
                <div class="handle"></div>
            </div>
        </label>
    </ion-item>
</div>
```

When `toggleClicked` is called, I output the value of `$event.target.value`. It doesn't matter whether the checkbox is checked or not, the value that is output is always `on`. I would have thought that once the checkbox is unchecked, the value would be returned as `off`?

I attempted to create a [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Xw7Xvh7QSy20eMYcUfsV?p=info) for this but it didn't want to work even though the code is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an issue with checkboxes and `ngClick`. [This handy SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19496821/clicking-a-checkbox-with-ng-click-does-not-update-the-model) points out that using `ngChange` instead works, though you'll need to associate it with a model.

In index.html:

```
<input ng-change="toggleClicked(member.id, member.checked)" type="checkbox" ng-model="member.checked" />
```

[Working plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/aVL8pcwWLcPMinZ8K0Fq?p=preview)