# Angularjs pass element to function

Tags: angularjs

As per core we used `this` for get element but in `AngularJS` we get `$scope` context.

So, I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26463491/angularjs-passing-this-value-into-a-function) question but without success.

Here is my attempt:

**Controller**

```
$scope.clickMe = function(ele) {
    console.log(ele);
    console.log(ele.id);
};
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="input-group">
    <input type="number" id="test-id" ng-blur="clickMe($event.target);">
</div>
```

How do I get the element in the function?

Comment: when you pass `this` like  `ng-blur="clickMe(this);"`, are you not getting element?

Comment: @Ved Nop.... it return `$scope` context.

Comment: Okay. than you can use `$event.currentTarget`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use :    **$event.currentTarget;**

```
 <div class="input-group">
        <input type="number" id="test-id" ng-blur="clickMe($event);">
    </div>

    $scope.clickMe = function(ele) {
        console.log(ele);
        console.log(ele.currentTarget);
    };
```

Fiddle" http://jsfiddle.net/h8to34ux/221/

Comment: +1 for 'event.currentTarget'. I did not know about this, but it is great for getting the element that actually contains the click handler, as opposed to 'event.target' which may instead point to a child element that was actually clicked on (for example, a <span> element inside of a button that owns the ng-click handler).

Answer (score 2):

your ng-blur event should send $event only like  ng-blur="clickMe($event);"

then in your controller

```
$scope.clickMe = function(ele) {    
    console.log(angular.element(ele));
    console.log(angular.element(ele).attr('id'));
};
```